# NodeJS ERROR: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'build\index.html'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

After a long connection time with my React application and many axios requests that lead to update useState variables i am getting this error on the frontend serving process

```
node:events:504
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
```

> ERROR: EMFILE: too many open files, open '[...]\Frontend\build\index.html'
> Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streans/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
> errno: -4066,
> code: 'EMFILE',
> syscall: 'open',
> path: '[...]\build\index.html'
> }

The frontend applicaiton is served on a server that is running windows

Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve this?
(Maybe an explenation on why this is happening)

Comment: Totally guessing, but does your code read/write files on the filesystem? If so, make sure that everything is properly closed after reading/writing, also looking at scenarios where an exception may occur.